# More Statemente after WHEN, THEN, ELSE in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

im trying to use the minus number of query to check and update my mysql db.
i have a dinamic value passed by an user, and when the result stored to the Db reach a limit, i will update another table with fixed value.

what bother me most is the following, it is possible after the THEN to update field, and also update a session variable?

```
WHEN(something) >= 50 THEN  50 AND @variable='setted yay'
```

thanks in advance for the info.

EDIT:

Ok i tring to update my query with your advice in mind, and here the result.

```
SET @ord:='prova';



UPDATE Users, Table2

SET Table2.field= CASE   
WHEN(Table2.field + 5) >= 50 AND IF( (Table2.field + 5) >= 50, (@ord='YAY GOOD'), '') IS NOT NULL
  THEN 50
WHEN(Table2.field + 5) <= -50 AND IF( (Table2.field + 5) <= -50, (@ord='YAY BAD'), '') IS NOT NULL
  THEN -50
ELSE (
    CASE
    WHEN(Table2.field + 5) > 25 AND IF( (Table2.field + 5) > 25, (@ord='YAY GOOD'), '') IS NOT NULL
        THEN (Table2.field + 5)
    WHEN(Table2.field + 5) < -25 AND IF( (Table2.field + 5) < -25, (@ord='YAY BAD'), '') IS NOT NULL
        THEN (Table2.field + 5)
        **ELSE (Table2.field+ 5 AND @ord:='YAY EQUILIBRIUM')**
        END
     )
END,

users.newalign= @ord

WHERE Table2.id = '338' AND users.id_user = Table2.id
```

obviusly the value 5 is merely an example i use to check if the sql il done correctly.

but now i encounter 2 problem.

1) it dont seems to accept the ELSE command in that way, maybe i fail at something.
2) i cannot pass the @ord onto the new modification. When the query runs without error the newalign field is everytime Empty :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the set into an "always true" condition:

```
CASE
  WHEN something >= 50
    AND IF(something >= 50, (@variable:='setted yay'), '') IS NOT NULL
  THEN 50
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply :) i edited my question with more dettail

Comment: sorry to bother you again, i edited the front question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You must use the `:=` operator to *set* a variable. Using `=` *compares* the variable with a value. All your `@ord='x'` statements must be changed to `@ord:='x'`